# Enterprise Miner copied project / cannot open

Tags: sas, enterprise-miner

we have the following problem. We tried, in the management console, in the folder view, to copy a miner project form one folder to another. If we try to open it from EM (Enterprise Miner) we get an error message:

"The selection is not a mining project"

If we try to open it from the original folder everything works perfectly. 
We have not moved the files on the filesystem. Only copied in the management console.
The user who is trying to open it has all the permissions to do so. I also tried with my username and I get the same problem. Anyone have any idea why?

Thanks in advance, Umberto

Answer (score 1):

The way that SAS products interface with Base SAS can be very complicated. Take a look at [SAS KB 32904](http://support.sas.com/kb/32/904.html), which gives a description on how to do move a project.

> 1. Copy the **project folder** from the current location to the new location using filesystem commands
> 2. Open SAS Enterprise Miner and select "View Metadata..."
> 3. Delete the project
> 4. Create a new project using the **same name** and specifying the new location

In your case, let's assume we have a project named "Foo" whose *project* folder (not the metadata folder) is in `C:\Have` and we want to move it to `C:\Want`.

Navigate to `C:\Have` and copy the folder `Foo` to `C:\Want`.

Next, open up Enterprise Miner, click `"View Metadata..."`, and find the metadata object for project `Foo`. Right click and delete. If you skip this step, SAS will error out at the last step of project creation saying that metadata for this project already exists.

[image]

Create a new project named `Foo`. Point its location to `C:\Want` (do not point it to `C:\Want\Foo`), and click `Next`.  EM will pause for a moment, and a box will pop up:

[image]

Click "Yes." After you are done creating the new project, you will find that all diagrams and datasets are restored.

Comment: Thank you very much. I know this method. Although thanks for taking the time of describing so well. My problem is that I don't want to move the files physically on the file system. I just want to change the folder in SAS, leaving the files where they are.

Comment: Ah, okay. Unfortunately, that's the maximum extent of my knowledge I've had when it comes to moving EM projects.

Comment: No problem. Thanks anyway. I have involved SAS Support. I will let you know what they say.